# Error trying to deploy strapi on heroku. grep and cut no recognized

Tags: powershell, heroku, window, strapi

I am deploying a strapi app to heroku, but i encounter an error, when i try to do:

> heroku config:set HEROKU_URL=$(heroku info -s | grep web_url | cut -d=
> -f2)

on vscode terminal and fails because grep and cut are not recognized.

Im follow the https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/deployment/heroku.html on windows SO

Can someone help me,  im stuck!

Answer (score 4):

You just have to set the URL of your Heroku app to the environment variable HEROKU_URL
If you don't know the URL, just type the command `heroku info -s` in the console.

It will list down a series of values like `key=value`. In that list, you can see an entry like
`web_url=https://xxx-yyy-nnnn.herokuapp.com/`

Once you get this value, you can just type the command to set the env variable as
`heroku config:set HEROKU_URL=https://xxx-yyy-nnnn.herokuapp.com/`